# Bgl breadth_first_search проблема хранения вершин

Tags: boost-bgl, c++

Привет всем! написал класс BFSVisitor чтобы сохранял пройденные вершины в векторе. Вот кусок кода

```
    class BFSVisitor : public boost::default_bfs_visitor
{
public:
    BFSVisitor() = default;
    ~BFSVisitor() = default;

    template<typename Vertex, typename Graph>
    void discover_vertex(Vertex u, Graph& g)
    {
        v.push_back(u);
    }

    vector<int> v;
};
```

но почему то он не сохраняет пройденный вершины...
и для меня еще очень странно, когда до вызова `boost::breadth_first_search(graph, A, boost::visitor(bfs));` вызываю из BFSVisitor вектор и сохраняю какое либо число, то после вызова `boost::breadth_first_search(graph, A, boost::visitor(bfs));` размер вектора как и остался равно 1 ...вот сам кусок кода

```
BFSVisitor bfs;
bfs.v.push_back(34);
boost::breadth_first_search(graph, A, boost::visitor(bfs));
cout<<endl;
cout<<bfs.v.size()<<endl;
```

как решить эту проблему, не применяя static ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [документации](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/breadth_first_search.html) сказано, что visitor передается в функцию по значению, т.е. копируется. Поэтому  пройденные вершины сохраняются в копии, которая в конце работы алгоритма уничтожается. Чтобы получить пройденные вершины можно, например, хранить в visitor-е указатель на внешний vector:

```
class BFSVisitor : public boost::default_bfs_visitor
{
public:
    explicit BFSVisitor(vector<int>* v)
       : v(v) {
    };
    ~BFSVisitor() = default;

    template<typename Vertex, typename Graph>
    void discover_vertex(Vertex u, Graph& g)
    {
        v->push_back(u);
    }

    vector<int>* v;
};

vector<int> visited_vertices;
BFSVisitor bfs(&visited_vertices);
boost::breadth_first_search(graph, A, boost::visitor(bfs));
cout<< visited_vertices.size()<<endl;
```